# Is UART necessary to send AT-commands to Bluetooth module?

Tags: avr, bluetooth, uart, atmel

I'm looking to alert a connected device over Bluetooth when an accelerometer detects motion. I'm thinking of using the [HM-10](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/images/c/cd/Bluetooth4_en.pdf) Bluetooth module and an ATtiny for controlling the accelerometer.

The doc says that AT-commands can only be sent via UART. Does that mean the ATTiny will need to have an UART port? Could an ATtiny45 be used instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module does require you to use the UART protocol in order to use it. It is possible to emulate a UART signal via bit banging, but this requires more from the MCU in order to make it work. [AVR304](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc0941.pdf) describes the most efficient way to do this.

Fortunately, the USI found in most tinyAVR devices, including the ATtinyX5, can be used as part of a half-duplex UART connection, alleviating some of the load. This is covered in [AVR307](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc4300.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for that module you will need to use a UART.

The ATtiny45 does not have a UART, therefore you won't be able to use it.

However, these [ATtinys](http://www.atmel.com/v2PFResults.aspx#%28actives:!%288238,8394,8362,8282,8431,8300,8358,8392,8378,8445,8236,8449,8474,8248,8264,8447,8256,8254,8286,8462,8429,8458,8466,8400,8302,8278%29,data:%28area:%27%27,category:%2734864[33180[33086]]%27,pm:!%28%28i:8238,v:!%281,7%29%29,%28i:8394,v:!%280,7%29%29,%28i:8362,v:!%285,12%29%29,%28i:8282,v:!%285%29%29,%28i:8431,v:!%281,8%29%29,%28i:8300,v:!%281,5%29%29,%28i:8358,v:!%282,20%29%29,%28i:8392,v:!%280,1%29%29,%28i:8378,v:!n%29,%28i:8445,v:!%285,6,9%29%29,%28i:8236,v:!%280,9%29%29,%28i:8449,v:!%281,3%29%29,%28i:8474,v:!%280%29%29,%28i:8248,v:!%280,1%29%29,%28i:8264,v:!%281,2%29%29,%28i:8447,v:!%280,1%29%29,%28i:8256,v:!%281,4%29%29,%28i:8254,v:!%283,16%29%29,%28i:8286,v:!%280%29%29,%28i:8462,v:!%281,2%29%29,%28i:8429,v:!%281,2%29%29,%28i:8458,v:!%280,1%29%29,%28i:8466,v:!%285%29%29,%28i:8400,v:!%280,7%29%29,%28i:8302,v:!%280%29%29,%28i:8278,v:!%280%29%29%29,view:table%29,sc:1%29) do have UARTs. Additionally, there are many other microcontrollers that have UARTs (PICs, other AVRs, STM8s, etc.).

Comment: But, contrary to the other answer, bit-banging could do, right?

Comment: Yes, you could bit-bang it. I didn't think to mention it in my answer. I prefer using a dedicated UART, especially if there is a lot of communication going on, which with a BLE module you may have. Bit-banging will take up more of the microcontroller's time, consume more power, be less reliable, usually jittery/glitchy. If it's interrupt driven then most of this is alleviated.